# Using libsodium between android and php

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, libsodium

I am using libsodium to encrypt data on client side, and decrypt on server side and vice-versa.
To be more exact, LazySodium on android side and php wrapper for libsodium on server side.

I am able to correctly encrypt and decrypt from android to android, and from php to php, but not from android to php.
On server side all decrypted variables from client side are blank(after decryption), no error is thrown.

Can anyone provide and example of proper encryption on Android(Java) and decyryption on php, using Lazy sodium and php wrapper for libsodium?

My Android code looks like this:

```
public String encrypt(Key privKey, Key serverPublicKey, String message, byte[] nonce) { // I use this function for every encryption
    KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(privKey, serverPublicKey);

    try {
        return box.cryptoBoxEasy(message, nonce, keyPair); // box is instance of Box.Lazy class
    } catch (SodiumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public byte[] randomNonce(){
    return lazySodium.randomBytesBuf(SecretBox.NONCEBYTES); // lazySodium Is instance of LazySodiumAndroid class
}

public KeyPair generateKeyPair() {
    try {
        return box.cryptoBoxKeypair(); 
    } catch (SodiumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And php code:

```
$nonce = sodium_hex2bin($nonce); // nonce is generated by client and send in hex

function register($name, $email, $pass, $public_key, $nonce)
{

echo $name." ".$email." ".$pass." ".$nonce."   "; //only for debug

$nonce = sodium_hex2bin($nonce);

$client_to_server_kp = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(sodium_hex2bin(KEY), sodium_hex2bin($public_key));

$name = sodium_crypto_box_open($name, $nonce, $client_to_server_kp);
$email = sodium_crypto_box_open($email, $nonce, $client_to_server_kp);
$pass = sodium_crypto_box_open($pass, $nonce, $client_to_server_kp);

// at this point these 3 variables are blank

if(empty($name) && empty($email) && empty($pass)){
    return 1;
}

@$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

if (@$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(email, name, password) VALUES (?,?,?)")) {
    @$stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $name, hash("SHA512", $pass));

    @$stmt->execute();

    $mysqli->close();

    return $stmt->errno;
}

$mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: What does your Android code and PHP code look like?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts added my code to question

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself.
The problem was that LazySodium saved encryped data as hex string, and php wrapper needed raw binary string to decrypt.

```
$password = sodium_hex2bin($password);
$email = sodium_hex2bin($email);
```

These two lines solved the problem.